# The module was expected to contain assembly manifest JNI4net error

Tags: .net, jni4net

I am trying to load XceedZip.dll in java using JNI4net/proxygen.
when proxygen command is executed I am getting Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Eclipse\JNITest\JNI\XceedZip.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Please find below the binder log entry

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (18-07-2020 @ 10:59:43) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80131018. No description available.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin\javaw.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: Where-ref bind. Location = C:\Eclipse\JNITest\JNI\XceedZip.dll
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_241/bin/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = javaw.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Eclipse/JNITest/JNI/XceedZip.dll.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Eclipse\Suraj_Selenium\JNI\XceedZip1.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
ERR: Error extracting manifest import from file (hr = 0x80131018).
ERR: Run-from-source setup phase failed with hr = 0x80131018.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131018). Probing terminated.
```

Comment: Searching stackoverflow for HR 0x80131018 yields [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671186/assembly-loadfile-throws-exception-about-missing-manifest)